# Using NodeJS buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, packet

I have following code:

```
var packet = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";
packet += "\x6D";
packet += "127.0.0.1:" + this.port;
packet += "\x00";
packet += this.name;
packet += "\x00";
packet += this.map;
packet += "\x00";
packet += "game1";
packet += "\x00";
packet += "x-z";
packet += "\x00";
packet += String.fromCharCode(this.players.length);
packet += String.fromCharCode(this.maxplayers);
packet += String.fromCharCode(this.protocol);
packet += "\x64";
packet += "\x6C";
packet += "\x00";
packet += "\x01";
packet += "\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00";
return new Buffer(packet, "binary");
```

I'm creating buffer from string now, but I think that this isn't good practice and string concatenation not efficient.
How I can replace this with Buffer functions and write to buffer directly?
I can't understand how Buffer works, for example, how to write 4 `\xFF` bytes at the beginning.

Thank you.

Comment: There will be no away around this, since you need to know the size of the buffer when you creating it.  
Depending on what you are planning to to maybe don't create a buffer and stream you data directly.

Comment: @TheHippo Hmm... What about fixed buffer size? I'm using packets with fixed (1400 bytes) length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of the packet is fixed, then could use [one of the many Buffer methods](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) to write directly to the buffer.

Initialize from a static string containing all you static data and leave the custom data blank. Later directly write the custom data into the buffer using precalculated offsets.

This could look somehow like this:

```
var static = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF.........";
var buff = new Buffer(static, 'binary');
buff.write(this.port, portStartOffset, portStringLength, 'binary');
```